# vb.net GUI designer in Monodevelop

Tags: vb.net, monodevelop

I'm using Monodevelop 5.1 and I'm trying to figure out how to access a GUI editor.  I know that there is a GUI designer for C#, but is there one for vb.net?

Comment: When the answer is very likely to be no, what's your plan?

Comment: Monodevelop doesn't support VB.NET as much as it supports C#, so this is most likely not possible.